How to insert a unicode text to PDF using PyMuPDF?
I'm trying to use the PyMuPDF library to insert a Unicode text into a PDF file. I have the following code based on the documentation example:
import pymupdf

doc = pymupdf.open()
page = doc.new_page()
p = pymupdf.Point(50, 72)

# String in Sinhala language
text = (
    "ශ්‍රී දළදා මාලිගාව යනු බුදුරජාණන් වහන්සේගේ වම් දන්තධාතූන් වහන්සේ වර්තමානයේ තැන්පත් කර ඇති මාළිගාවයි."
)

font = pymupdf.Font(fontfile="ISKPOTAB.TTF") # Font file of the default Windows Sinhala font
page.insert_font(fontbuffer=font.buffer) # using font buffer since using name "Iskoola Pota Bold" produce an error
rc = page.insert_text(p, text, fontfile=font.buffer, fontsize=11, rotate=0)
print("%i lines printed on page %i." % (rc, page.number))

doc.save("text.pdf")

This code runs without any errors. However, the pdf file it produces only has dots(".").

Am I missing anything here or it's just that PyMuPDF does not support unicode insertion?

Solution using insert_htmlbox letting PyMuPDF determine all fonts automatically.
import pymupdf

doc = pymupdf.open()
page = doc.new_page()

sinhalese_text = (
    "ශ්‍රී දළදා මාලිගාව යනු බුදුරජාණන් වහන්සේගේ වම් දන්තධාතූන් වහන්සේ වර්තමානයේ තැන්පත් කර ඇති මාළිගාවයි."
)

page.insert_htmlbox((50, 100, 300, 300), sinhalese_text)

doc.subset_fonts()
doc.ez_save("text.pdf")
doc.close()

Gives you this:

As this method also accepts HTML and CSS syntax, you can influence everything that is in reach of your HTML knowledge ... 

I'm curios to hear from people who can read Sinhalese if this also gets around the incorrect writing issues. It certainly looks a bit cleaner, but I'm not sure if this is just printing characters more cleanly, or actually correctly writes the entire phrase.

@Grismar This solution renders the text correctly. Since this solution aligns more with the original question, I will mark this as the accepted answer. Thank you!

@Jorj McKie I noticed something odd about this even though it renders text correctly. When I page.get_text() on the output pdf of this script, it returns junk. However, the pdf produced by @Grismar's script gives back the correct text when page.get_text() is used. Any insights into this behaviour? Thank you!

I agree with your choice - I'd be interested to hear from anyone who knows if it's possible to achieve the same with Fitz without the HTML intermediate step, but it's good to have a solution that works as intended.

You may need some further adjustments, I can't read Sinhalese, but this produces a PDF with your text in both Nirmala UI and Iskoola Pota:
import fitz  # PyMuPDF

doc = fitz.open()
page = doc.new_page()

# load and add the font, and name them for Fitz (PyMuPDF)
page.insert_font(fontname='F0', fontfile=r'C:\Windows\Fonts\Nirmala.ttf')
page.insert_font(fontname='F1', fontfile=r'C:\Temp\Fonts\iskpotab.ttf')

sinhalese_text = "ශ්‍රී දළදා මාලිගාව යනු බුදුරජාණන් වහන්සේගේ වම් දන්තධාතූන් වහන්සේ වර්තමානයේ තැන්පත් කර ඇති මාළිගාවයි."

# insert the text twice, using both fonts
font_size = 24
page.insert_text((50, 100), sinhalese_text, fontname='F0', fontsize=font_size)
page.insert_text((50, 150), sinhalese_text, fontname='F1', fontsize=font_size)

doc.save("text.pdf")
doc.close()

Note: as far as I can tell, the text reads "The Temple of the Tooth Relic is the temple where the left tooth relic of the Buddha is currently enshrined."

It works. However, it does not render the text correctly. I do not see a way to fix that. Thank you and your translation of the string is spot on!

If you don't care about the text being actual text in the PDF, there may be ways to render the text as images using other libraries in Python and then adding the images to the PDF. If the image library you use for that can generate vector graphics, that would be even better - but the text wouldn't be selectable, copy-able and searchable in the PDF, so probably not ideal.

@paarandika it is unlikely to display text correctly.what is stored in the PDF are visually ordered glyphs rather than actual text.

@Grismar The main goal of this investigation is to create PDF Unicode letters. So having images is not an option.

@Andj PDF supports correct rendering of Sinhala language. I guess it needs to be correctly rendered before writing to PDF. Which PyMuPDF doesn't seem to support.

In PyMuPDf, methods insert_text(), insert_textbox() write text character-by-character. In complex scripting systems like here, additional text shaping like provided by Harfbuzz is needed. To achieve this with PyMuPDF use a different method , page.insert_htmlbox(). It inokes Harfbuzz and also auto-selects all needed fonts from Google NOTO. Documentation here.

You can also provide your own fonts if needed. Look at this recipe.

Note that the answer already provides an example with a downloaded font.
